# Column '' in field list is ambiguous. (when JOIN ON)

Tags: sql

> Column 'company_id' in field list is ambiguous

It does not seem "ambiguous", I have no idea where I should fix it:

```
SELECT company_id, companies.name 
FROM company_contracts AS contracts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON companies.id = contracts.company_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_logs AS logs ON companies.id = logs.company_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `company_id` appears on both table `company_contracts` and `order_logs`,you need to specify it

```
SELECT contracts.company_id,c1.name 
FROM company_contracts as contracts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies as c1 on c1.id = contracts.company_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_logs as logs on c1.id = logs.company_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should qualify all columns names in such a query.  In addition, if you really want outer joins, the second `join` condition should refer to the *first* table, not the *second*:

```
SELECT cc.company_id, c.name 
FROM company_contracts cc LEFT OUTER JOIN
     companies c
     ON c.id = cc.company_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     order_logs ol
     ON cc.company_id = ol.company_id;
```

Or, more likely, you want to keep all companies and the query should look like:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name 
FROM companies c  LEFT OUTER JOIN
     company_contracts cc
     ON c.id = cc.company_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     order_logs ol
     ON c.id = ol.company_id;
```